# Not able to mount/install vmware tools

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-tools

I'm using the vmware player 6. I installed Mint 15 Olivia (MATE 64bit), everything is fine...except that I cannot install vmware tools.
When I start the vm and click im vmware menu: **player/manage/install vmware tools...** nothing happens. I should get a message that somewhere something is happening, actually my os should show me that vmware tools are mounted.

Somehow like here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnHfA5Cu_Is

I did the same thing. I cannot find any images. There is also no log in vmware (**player/manage/Message Log**). Maybe I have to mount manually(?), I tried something like:

```
vmuser@vmware ~ $ sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like your drive is not connected to the VM. To connect the drive the follow the steps below.
[image: go to vm settings]
[image: configure how you the cd drive to be connected]

If this is not what you're looking for, please add more details to your question.