# Can't install VMware tools on Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I just downloaded VMWare player 6.0.3 because I had major issues with VirtualBox. I need to share a folder and for this, I need VMware tools.

I tried clicking Player>Manage>Install VMware tools: the yellow footer thing shows up, instructing me to open a terminal and mount the disk, but nothing else happens. I can't mount the dvd manually either:
"sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom" gives "mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0"

[image]

Also, I know there are ISO's available online [here](http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/index.html), but I'm not sure which to pick...

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/660739/not-able-to-mount-install-vmware-tools) question is related but seems to be abondoned by the user.

Comment: How do you decribe the machine in VM Player? May be as _Linux - Other *.* kernel_? Try to describe it as Ubuntu and start the machine. If Vm Player cannot detect the guest OS, it uses this description to download the proper tools.

Comment: That works! I thought that version detection was the problem but it didn't occur to set the version to Ubuntu. If you post as an answer I will accept! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you decribe the machine in VM Player? May be as Linux - Other *.* kernel? Try to describe it as Ubuntu and start the machine. If VM Player cannot detect the guest OS, it uses this description to download the proper tools.